# Webpack doesn't pick up the latest changes in my JS files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I just started learning React and was asked to start using webpack as a JS bundler. Every time I change a JS file and save the changes, a new compilation is triggered in "npm run watch" window. But, my webpack compilation doesn't pick up the changes in my JS code. Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "tryReact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./webpack",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --entry ./src/index.js --output-path ./webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.17",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.17",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.24.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

here is webpack.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I have to delete the main.js in the --output-path directory and then recompile it for the changes to take effect. If it matters, I use Atom as and editor and these JS files are constantly open in my editor. I tried switching back to Vim. But no use. I also tried "npm run dev" without any success. What am I missing?

Comment: try adding `--watch` flag do `dev` . How do You run npm server ? With `npm run dev` ?

Comment: another thing is, I had issues with setting flags in this modes. Try to define `entry` and `output` in `webpack.config.js`

Comment: It worked correctly. I removed the "watch": "webpack --watch"  line from scripts and added --watch flag directly to dev as per your suggestion.  I was earlier running 'npm run watch'. Now I am running 'npm run dev' and it is watching for the changes correctly.